# Is it possible to use inline templates?

Tags: ansible

I need to create a single file with the contents of a single fact in Ansible. I'm currently doing something like this:

```
- template: src=templates/git_commit.j2 dest=/path/to/REVISION
```

My template file looks like this:

```
{{ git_commit }}
```

Obviously, it'd make a lot more sense to just do something like this:

```
- inline_template: content={{ git_revision }} dest=/path/to/REVISION
```

Puppet offers something similar. Is there a way to do this in Ansible?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Another option to the [lineinfile](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html) module (as given by [udondan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2753241/udondan)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33770871/2291321)) would be to use the [copy](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html) module and specify the content rather than a source local to the Ansible host.

An example task would look something like:

```
- name: Copy commit ref to file
  copy:
    content: "{{ git_commit }}"
    dest: /path/to/REVISION
```

I personally prefer this to `lineinfile` as for me `lineinfile` should be for making slight changes to files that are already there where as `copy` is for making sure a file is in a place and looking exactly like you want it to. It also has the benefit of coping with multiple lines.

In reality though I'd be tempted to make this a template task and just have a the template file be:

```
"{{ git_commit }}"
```

Which gets created by this task:

```
- name: Copy commit ref to file
  template:
    src: path/to/template
    dest: /path/to/REVISION
```

It's cleaner and it's using modules for exactly what they are meant for.

Comment: is the src and dest backwards? i think you want src: /path/to/REVISION if that is your template.  The OP has a good question.  It would be nice to go directly from inline content without having to go through an intermediate.

Comment: Using the copy command does seem to work, but the copy documentation (as of v2.9) https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html has this scary warning: "If you need variable interpolation in copied files, use the template module. Using a variable in the content field will result in unpredictable output."  What do we make of that?

Comment: It looks like that was added to close https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/34595 but the issue there is around variables/content that aren't simple string types which I don't think is really valid here.

Comment: this is wrong suggestion: according to https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/50580, content should not have variables

Answer (score 6):

Yes, in that simple case it is possible with the [`lineinfile`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html) module.

```
- lineinfile:
  dest=/path/to/REVISION
  line="{{ git_commit }}"
  regexp=".*"
  create=yes
```

The `lineinfile` module usually is used to ensure that a specific line is contained inside a file. The `create=yes` option will crete the file if it does not exist. The `regexp=.*` option makes sure you do not add content to the file if `git_commit` changes, because it would by default simply make sure the new content is added to the file and not replace the previous content.

This only works since you only have one line in your file. If you'd had more lines this obviously would not work with this module.

Answer (score 2):

This issue seems to be resolved. However, if the template file was more than one variable, i.e. a json file, it is possible to use copy module with content parameter, with a **lookup**, i.e.:

```
# playbook.yml
---
- name: deploy inline template
  copy:
    content: '{{ lookup("template", "inlinetemplate.yml.j2") }}'
    dest: /var/tmp/inlinetempl.yml

# inlinetemplate.yml.j2
---
- name: {{ somevar }}
  abc: def
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need insert the template to the exist file, you can insert through the lineinfile module.

```
- name: Insert jinja2 template to the file
  lineinfile:
    path: /path/file.conf
    insertafter: "after this line"
    line: "{{ lookup('template', 'template.conf.j2') }}"
```